# Cannot cast InputPeerChat to any kind of InputChannel

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegraf

I have created a bot using Telegraf. I want that when a user sends a message, the bot will send him the previous message. So I want to take the previous post on id with Gram JS but throws this error

[image]

here is my code:

```
   bot.on("message", async (ctx) => {
    const { text, message_id } = ctx.message;
    const userId = ctx.from.id;

    const replyToMessage = await client.invoke(
      new Api.channels.GetMessages({
        channel: `${ctx.chat.id}`,
        id: [message_id - 1],
      })
    );

    console.log(1234, replyToMessage);

    ctx.reply(replyToMessage);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I was inspecting telegram telethon api for a python task. I have some thougths about your issue.

The thing is telegram says it can not find anything with that id and channel. But I have some questions about your code.

As far as I know telegram either asks for a channel_id and channel_access_hash or the channel_username.
I am seeing that you give the telegram a channel_id and message_id ?

You should check your api docs again and try to find a method you can directly use the channel's username.

Note on that username : Telegram group or chat must be public or you must be auth, and (as far as python telethon) you must add the https:// appendix to channel_username.

I hope you can find a way out. If you further detail your question we can talk it again, I have spend plenty of time with python's telethon api.